# Is there any performance gain from using Lambda expression for implementing Interfaces?

Tags: java, lambda, interface, expression

Here is my example Interface

```
package lambdaexpressions;

public interface Animal {
    
//  public void move(int i);
    public void sound();
}
```

I am implementing this interface in a class

```
package lambdaexpressions;

public class InterfaceWithLambda {
    
    public static void main() {
    
    Animal a;
    
//  a = move(i) ->  System.out.println("inside move" + i); 
    a = () ->
             { System.out.println("inside sound");
               System.out.println("walk");
             };
             
    a.sound();
    
    
    }
}
```

I want to know is there any performance gain in using Lambda expression instead of using Anonymous class for implementing Interface?

And my second question is why exactly one method must be present in the Interface in order to use lambda expression?

Like I can't implement the overloaded method or multiple methods present in the Interface.

Comment: "*And my second question is why exactly one method must be present in the Interface in order to use lambda expression?*" if the interface had two methods defined, how would you implement both with a single lambda?

Comment: If I can't do that so the question still remains is there any performance gain using Lambda expression?
Because if we can only implement the interface with only one method just for the sake of easy code writing. I rather use an anonymous class if there is no difference in perfomance.

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted -- it seems like a reasonable question, even if one that would be difficult to answer in a general sense. With at least some lambda expressions I've noted that the compiler generates different bytecode from the use of an inner class. So there is at least the potential for differences in throughput. But whether they are significant, I have no idea.

Comment: @KevinBoone Same is with Type inference, they say it reduces complexity and makes code easier to read and with lots of restrictions.